# Memory allocation for a class that has explicit initializers

Tags: c++, initialization, dynamic-memory-allocation

When I allocate memory for say, some integers, I do it this way:

```
int* pointer = new int[10];
```

Same thing works for class object pointers too:

```
int dim = 5;
Complex* vect = new Complex[dim];
```

But if, say, I have a class with explicit initializer like so:

```
class Vec
{
private:
    int dim;
    Complex *vect;
public:
    Vec(int n):dim(n){
        vect=new Complex[dim];
    }
};
```

Then what is the correct syntax to initialize a pointer to the class object and allocate memory for say, 5 of them?

```
Vec* u=new Vec(dim)[5];
```

Doesn't seem to be the correct syntax.

I tried:

```
    Vec* u=new Vec[2]{Vec(dim),Vec(dim)};
```

but that gives the error:

```
Rajats-MacBook-Pro:codes rajat$ g++ vector.cpp 
vector.cpp:340:16: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'Vec [2]'
    Vec* u=new Vec[2]{Vec(dim),Vec(dim)};
               ^
vector.cpp:67:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single
      argument 'n', but no arguments were provided
    Vec(int n):dim(n){
    ^
vector.cpp:58:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not
      viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class Vec
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Edit: The full code is uploaded here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/TwsLAjg4J9tyXQEz
It works in WandBox.

The version details of the compiler I'm using is:

```
Rajats-MacBook-Pro:codes rajat$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Thank you.

Update: problem solved. I needed to add the compiler flag

```
-std=c++11
```

It now works using all the methods suggested here.

Comment: How about using our lord and savior  `std::vector`?

Comment: Not clear: Do you mean 5 instances of `Vec` or that `u->vect` must be of size 5?

Comment: @acraig5075 5 instances. Without the explicit initilizer dim, it would seem like Vec* u=new Vec[5]; and that works. however, with the explicit initilizer, i don't quite  know what the correct syntax should be

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that might work, let me see if i can change the code

Comment: There's also a standard complex number class if `Complex` is supposed to be those.

Comment: It should work. The error suggests that there are something else in your file that makes fail. So post all of vector.cpp exactly as it is.

Comment: @4386427 Done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be:

```
Vec* u = new Vec[5]{Vec(4), Vec(8), Vec(15), Vec(16), Vec(23)};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a995eff61033c69)

But prefer `std::vector`.

Comment: this doesn't work either. `Vec* u=new Vec[2]{Vec(dim),Vec(dim)};` gives `no matching constructor for initialization of 'Vec [2]'`. I will update the full info in the question.

Comment: @RajatMondal: Demo link added.

Comment: How can I find out why it doesn't compile in my case?

Comment: Do you compile in C++03 mode?

Comment: @Jarod42 no. I don't use any flags whatsoever. It's the default g++ compiler that comes with macOS

Comment: Which version, so?

Comment: @RajatMondal Take a copy of the code provided in the demo link of this answer (or in my comment) and compile that simple code on your machine... does it work?

Comment: @RajatMondal If your compiler is `g++`, then run `g++ version`. If your compiler version is lower than 6.1, then default standard is C++98, which is terribly old (and doesn't support brace initialization for example). You can change standard version by adding `-std=c++11` or higher (c++14, c++17)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `g++ --version` isn't it?

Comment: @4386427 Yes, my bad :)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes, adding the compiler flag worked. Thank you so much. ☺️

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `std::vector` instead. For instance this here:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Vec> u(5, 3);
}
```

Makes a vector of `5` `Vec` with `3` `Complex` each. However, the constructor is only called once and then it's copied five times, so you need to implement a copy constructor, otherwise they would all share one instance of `vect`:

```
Vec(const Vec& other){
        std::cout << "copied size " << other.dim << std::endl;
        dim = other.dim;
        vect = new int[dim];
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            vect[i] = other.vect[i];
    }
```

And in order to not have a memory leak, you also need a destructor:

```
~Vec() {
    delete[] vect;
    std::cout << "deleted " << dim << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work either but after compiling using c++11 it does, but so does my original code. so thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Both are not the same case, in the first you know the size of the vector at compiling time. Better try to use the std::vector, in this way you don't need to worry about memory administration.

```
class Vec
{
private:
    int dim;
    std::vector<Complex> vect;
public:
    Vec(int n):dim(n){
        vect.resize(dim);
    }
};
```